# `Import` root path in a Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have the following extension folder structure.

```
.
├── background
│   ├── page.html
│   └── src
│       ├── other_script.js
│       └── script.js
└── manifest.json
```

In `manifest.json`, I'm loading `page.html`:

```json
{
    // ...

    "background":
    {
        "page": "background/page.html"
    }
}
```

`page.html` itself loads a script:

```html
<script type="module" src="src/script.js"></script>
```

And that script then imports other scripts in my extension:

```js
// Inside script.js
import data from "/background/src/other_script.js";
```

Here's what I am wondering. The path prefixed by `/` in the `import` statement above seems to be relative to my extension directory (that is, where `manifest.json` is located). I am curious if:

1. I can change what directory `/` is relative to, for example to `/background/src`, so that the following is valid:

```js
import data from "/other_script.js";
```

or,

2. I can define an extension-wide variable such as `SRC` so that I can rewrite the `import` as follows:

```js
import data from `${SRC}/other_script.js`;
```

Comment: have you tried ./other_scripts.js or just 'other_script.js'?

Comment: A relative path works for this example, but if the importing file is `background/src/a/b/c/c_script.js` I'd still like `import "/other_script.js"` to work.